# How to describe the four-current of a tilted loop in Kerr spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, electric-current, kerr-metric

consider the [Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)
We usually describe the source of an electromagnetic field by the four vector $J^\mu$.
$$J^\mu = \{\rho, j^1, j^2, j^3\}.$$
Now we have an axial current loop we the vector becomes
$$
J^\mu_{\text{axial current loop}} = \{0,0,0,C \delta(r-r_0) \delta(\theta-\pi/2)\}
$$
Where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function. $r_0$ is the radial distance of the current loop. $C$ is some constant, we would have to introduce some class of observers to relate it to actual current.

This seems quite intuitive and obvious.

But I want to "tilt" the source. So that the loop isn't axial anymore.
I've created a graphic for this since I've found it hard to explain what I mean (the arrow is the axis of symmetry)

The red loop is described by$J^\mu_{\text{axial current loop}} $.

How would we describe green loop by the four vector $J^\mu$?

Edit:

The field would probably have a non-zero component $j^2$. This again would be some constant related to "actuall" current in some way.

What I can't figure out is form of the Dirac delta arguments.
The four-vector will probrably look like

$$
J^\mu_{\text{non-axial current loop}}= \{0,0,A,B\} \delta(r-r_0) \delta(F(\theta,\phi))
$$

Where $A,B$ are constants, $F$ is the function I'm trying to find.

Or perhaps even

$$
J^\mu_{\text{non-axial current loop}}= \{0,0,A\ \delta(H(\theta,\phi)),B\ \delta(G(\theta,\phi))\} \delta(r-r_0) 
$$

where $G,H$ are the functions that I'm trying to find.

Edit 2: upon further consideration, it is perhaps not true that the dependance on $r$ will be as easy as $\delta(r-r_0)$ since we do not have spherical symmetry.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to describe a current loop outside a Kerr black hole? You're going to run into a problem - since there's no spherical symmetry, there's no obvious notion of a tilted circle. Is it enough to pretend that space is flat and describe a tilted circle in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I want to describe a titled circle, if no other answer are available I would probably accept the description in flat-space since it at least builds intuition.

Comment: Yes, I started working it out, but the math turned out to be not so simple. If I have time I'll try to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with assuming the ring to be made of individual particles that go in a spherical orbit, then we can reduce this problem to treating a single particle.

In this case of a test particle in spherical motion around a Kerr black hole, its motion can be reduced to solving these equations (where $E, L, Q$ is the total energy w.r.t infinity, the axis-symmetric component of angular momentum and Carter const for the particle motion,  see  [[1]](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1972ApJ...178..347B&defaultprint=YES&page_ind=0&filetype=.pdf) section I for more information):
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
& \Sigma \frac{d r}{d \lambda}= \pm\left(V_r\right)^{1 / 2}, \\
& \Sigma \frac{d \theta}{d \lambda}= \pm\left(V_\theta\right)^{1 / 2}, \\
& \Sigma \frac{d \varphi}{d \lambda}=-\left(a E-L / \sin ^2 \theta\right)+a T / \Delta, \\
& \Sigma \frac{d t}{d \lambda}=-a\left(a E \sin ^2 \theta-L\right)+\left(r^2+a^2\right) T / \Delta .
\end{aligned}
$$

If we write the metric in a generic form
$$
d s^2=-e^{2 v} d t^2+e^{2 \psi}(d \varphi-\omega d t)^2+e^{2 \lambda} d r^2+e^{2 \mu} d \theta^2 ,
$$

then it can be shown that in the frame of a locally inertial zero-angular momentum (ZAMO) observer [[2](https://astro.vaporia.com/start/zamoframe.html.)], the velocity $\beta$ for a particle in a (generic) spherical orbit (i.e., $\beta^r = 0$) takes the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \beta^{\varphi}=\frac{\tilde{L}}{\tilde{E-}\omega \tilde{L}} e^{v-\psi}, \\
& \beta^{\theta}=\left[1-\frac{e^{2 v}\left(1+e^{-2 \psi} \tilde{L}{ }^2\right)}{\left(\tilde{E}-\omega \tilde{L}\right)^2}\right]^{1 /2}, \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\tilde{E} = E/\mu$ and the same for $\tilde{L}$, $\mu$ being the rest mass of the particle and $\omega$ is the frame dragging angular velocity as measured from infinity. If you want to convert from the ZAMO frame to the BL coordinates, you can follow the approach in section III of  [[1]](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1972ApJ...178..347B&defaultprint=YES&page_ind=0&filetype=.pdf). Note that for a rotating black hole, the particle won't remain restricted to a plane due to the [Lense-Thirring effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession).

This paper [[4](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1987SvAL...13...99S&defaultprint=YES&page_ind=0&filetype=.pdf)] might also be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Actually consider the loop to be a ring of rotating particles may be a good idea. Anyways there is still some work to be done to relate these orbit to a four-current that satisfies the continuity equations $ (-g)^{-1/2} \partial_{x^\mu} ((-g)^{1/2} J^\mu) = 0$. 
Also, ideally, it would be great that such a vector is independent of $t$, since that allows us to separate the Maxwell equations.
I'll accept the answer before the bounty runs out if nothing better shows up.